# How can we push New Element in firestore Map type array in Android/java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my case i have an array of Map type which name is players.when i click on join button from application i want new player add in this array.

[image: as you see players array in collection field]

```
  Map<String,Object> playerMap=new HashMap<>();
                playerMap.put("name","adnan");
                playerMap.put("subtitle","bashir");
                playerMap.put("image","url");
                playerMap.put("documentID","id2");

   FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                db.collection("matchesPRO").document("5mr4xk7I3InAe8LR2SbJ").update("players",playerMap);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an item to an array, you can use the `arrayUnion()` method as follows:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("matchesPRO").document("docID");

// Atomically add a new player Map to the "players" array field.
docRef.update("players", FieldValue.arrayUnion(playerMap));
```

Comment: i already try this way but not worked for me ... i dont know whats wrong

Comment: Are you getting any error message or you just see the data not being added?

Comment: there is no error showing to me...but data not added too

Comment: Please, update your question to show how you're implementing the `arrayUnion()` method in your code. Are you following any documentation or tutorials for this? The following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) should help you with this.